# Is this actually a circular dependency, or a false positive?

Tags: angular

### The Setup

I have two components in play here:

- `SliderComponent`
- `SlideComponent`

They are both a part of `SliderModule`.  As I am sure you have guessed by now one is a slider, and the other is each slide for the slider.  It is implemented as follows:

```
<app-slider>
    <app-slide>
        <p>Slide content!</p>
    </app-slide>
</app-slider>
```

### The Problem

In order for `SliderComponent` to have a reference to each `SlideComponent` injected via content projection, it calls:

```
@ContentChildren(SlideComponent) public slides: QueryList<SlideComponent>;
```

Sweet no problem.  But now in order to keep all of the functionality in `SliderComponent` where it belongs, each slide needs a reference to the `SliderComponent`, so it calls:

```
constructor( @Inject(forwardRef(() => SliderComponent)) public slider: SliderComponent){}
```

### The question

Is this *actually* a circular dependency, or is it a false positive?

The reason I believe it is a false-positive is that I can AOT compile just fine with no issues and no lag, and the entire app works just fine.

Is it ok to just leave this here? Should I file a bug report for this? Or is it actually a problem I should try to find a work-around for?

Comment: try the "slide" don't need "slider". You can use Output to emit some value to parent or use a service to share some variables. It's only a personal opinion, if we need Inject a component we need re-thinking the problem (I can't say that it's wrong, simply I don't like)

Comment: I disagree, component injection is there for a reason, and it's exactly for situations like this to avoid unnecessary services when there needs to be simple communication between two components, especially in a parent/child relationship like this one.  Of course, opinions aside, we still have no idea whether this is a false positive or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Stephen, I can't imagine me doing something like @Inject(forwardRef(() => SliderComponent)

Imagine your components

```
<app-slider>
   <app-slide (command)="Command($event)" [data]="dataShared">
</app-slider>
```

Your app-slider

```
export interface ICommand
{
     command:int;
     data:any;
}

dataShared:any={title:"Title",date:New Date()}

Command(command:ICommand)
{
    switch (command.command)
    {
          case 1:
                method1(command.data);
                break; 
          case 2:
               method2();
               break;
    }
}
```

Your app_slide

```
@Input() data; //We can use all the sharedData from parent
@Output() command= new EventEmitter<ICommand>();

  doSomething() {
    this.command.emit({command:1,data:this.largeData});
  }
  doSomethingMore() {
    this.command.emit({command:2});
  }
```

Comment: In my particular scenario I do not have control over the implementation of the `app-slide` tags, so I do not have a way to implement this, which is what component injection is for, as I mentioned previously. The end goal is to have the implementation of the slider be as code-blind to the implementer as possible. While I could indeed use a service to accomplish the same behavior I personally dislike having services that only serve to pass one or two values back and forth between components when they can simply access each other directly.  Also this doesn't answer the original question.